# SAP BAPI function to read MICs for material X

Tags: sap-erp, bapi

I need to read Master Inspection Characteristics (MICs) for material X on plant Y. I need result to be MIC number, Test Description, Upper Specs, Lower Specs.

I have tried `BAPI_INSPCHAR_GETREQUIREMENTS`, but it takes Inspection Lot as input. I need to get it from Material number (`MATNR`).

If quite difficult, how to get from SAP table. I have data from the tables `MAPL`, `PLAS`, `PLKO`, `PLPO`, `PLMK`, but I do not know how to relate these tables to get MICs for material X.

Thanks.